# Image is uploaded to server but not shown in Imageview application android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-volley, android-glide, imagedownload

I have created photo uploading feature. User can take photo and choose a photo from a file and upload it to the Server.

At this moment the photo is uploaded successfully to server. But when i look at my app, it is showing the old image. the image is not updated in the imageview in my app. I have heared about the shared preferance by which user can set their image as long as they want.

I am using the Volley library to POST data from my app to upload the photo, and using the Glide library to download and show that photo into the app.

I am giving a small portion of my code, which is related to photo uploading and downloading. Please help me to identify and solve the problem.

```
public void showDialog(){
        ........
        alertButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                alert.dismiss();
            }
        });

        alertListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // ListViekw Clicked item index
                if (position == 0) {

                        cameraIntent();

                }
                else if (position == 1){

                        galleryIntent();

                }
            }
        });
    }


    private void galleryIntent()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),SELECT_FILE);

    }

    public void cameraIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
            File cameraFolder;
            if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
                cameraFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "image/");
            } else {
                cameraFolder = getActivity().getCacheDir();
            }
            if (!cameraFolder.exists()) {
                cameraFolder.mkdirs();
            }
            String imageFileName = System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
            File photoFile = new File(cameraFolder + imageFileName);
            currentPhotoPath = photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
            if (photoFile != null) {
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE){
                onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);

            }

            else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(currentPhotoPath)) {
                    galleryAddPic();
                    onCaptureImageResult();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void galleryAddPic() {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        File f = new File(currentPhotoPath);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        this.getActivity().sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }

    private void onCaptureImageResult() {
        Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromPath(currentPhotoPath, 200, 200);
        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        compressBitMap(bitmap);
    }

    private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {
        ...
    }


    private void compressBitMap(Bitmap bitmap) {
       ...
    }

    public static Bitmap getBitmapFromPath(String photoPath, int targetW, int targetH) {
        ....
    }

    private void uploadImage(final byte[] bytesArray){


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A common mistake with image loading to a server is using the same url for the new image. In this case, glide will use the previous image that it already cached.
There are 2 **solutions**:

1. a good solution - the server should use a time stamp in the url it assigned to an image.
2. a bad solution - to skip the cache with glide (skipMemoryChache()).

Comment: I have tied the second one (a bad solution) but that does not work at all. could please explain a bit more about the better solution. It would be really helpful for me. I stuck with this isse from yesterday. I am still very new in android developing.

Comment: Is there any way to replace the previous image when I upload the new image,

Comment: The first solution is within the server - when the server assigns a url for the image, you probably use a user id in it, right? Then put in a time as well, maybe something like that: http:/mydomain/uploadimage&user=userid&time=20170920183312

Answer (score 0):

you have entered the zeroth position of list, so it displays old image.